# Upload word document as answer

Tags: discussion

This might seem as a stupid question but I would like to upload a word document as an answer to a question. I can convert the document to html and copy its contents but most of the formula disappear when pasting into the stack exchange answer box.
I dont have a website, which could refer the interested people to an URL. I do have Google Drive and a shared folder, but how can I reference this folder in the answer box.

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot type the formulae as MathJax?

Comment: FYI posting a link to a Word document would probably get deleted as not-an-answer, so even if you did have a website, I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 5):

We generally like answers to be written using the markup facilities provided so they are searchable. That's why we deprecate the posting of images containing the working. If your answer was a screengrab of the document or just a link to the document it would not be very popular.

Whenever I want to compose a long answer I generally write in Word then copy and paste into this site. However I will have already used MathJax to format equations. I'm guessing you've used the Word equation editor or something similar for equations. In that case the only option is to rewrite the equations using MathJax.

If redoing the equations is impossibly time consuming then I'm afraid the best option is not to answer at all.

A last desparate option might be to post a link to the document in the chat room and ask if anyone would be interested in converting the equations to MathJax. If it's one of the areas I'm particularly interested in (e.g. GR) then I might be willing.

Comment: I agree with this, though I would point out that we do extend some leniency on MathJax to new users who may not have heard of it before. If a new user posts unformatted formulas, someone will usually go through and help with the formatting the first few times. Of course we do expect people to learn it for themselves before too long.

Comment: Another option for editing long answers before posting is https://stackedit.io. You can edit posts in mardown, see them live, and save them to google drive and similar services. (No relation; I find it useful but don't use it that often.)

Comment: I have had a similar issue with Word.  It would be convenient if an experienced programmer developed an application that converted Word equations into MathJax equations.

Comment: @DavidWhite: on that subject [I found this post that might interest you](http://superuser.com/questions/198358/differences-between-mathtype-and-equation-editor-format-in-microsoft-word).

Comment: @JohnRennie, thanks.  I'll read your link in detail and play around with it to see if I can avoid retyping Word equations.